# Laravel 5 composer install fails (psysh, php-parser, ext-tokenizer errors)

Tags: php, laravel, installation, composer-php, laravel-5

Running `$ composer create-project laravel/laravel` fails with error:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.1)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

Created project in /Users/androidu/Workspace/phpstorm/laravel
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.0.6 requires psy/psysh 0.3.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.3.0, v0.3.1, v0.3.2, v0.3.3, v0.3.4, v0.3.5].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.5 requires psy/psysh 0.3.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.3.0, v0.3.1, v0.3.2, v0.3.3, v0.3.4, v0.3.5].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.4 requires psy/psysh 0.3.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.3.0, v0.3.1, v0.3.2, v0.3.3, v0.3.4, v0.3.5].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.3 requires psy/psysh 0.3.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.3.0, v0.3.1, v0.3.2, v0.3.3, v0.3.4, v0.3.5].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.2 requires psy/psysh 0.3.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.3.0, v0.3.1, v0.3.2, v0.3.3, v0.3.4, v0.3.5].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.1 requires psy/psysh 0.3.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.3.0, v0.3.1, v0.3.2, v0.3.3, v0.3.4, v0.3.5].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.0 requires psy/psysh 0.3.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.3.0, v0.3.1, v0.3.2, v0.3.3, v0.3.4, v0.3.5].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.10 requires psy/psysh 0.4.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.4.0, v0.4.1].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.11 requires psy/psysh 0.4.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.4.0, v0.4.1].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.12 requires psy/psysh 0.4.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.4.0, v0.4.1].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.13 requires psy/psysh 0.4.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.4.0, v0.4.1].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.14 requires psy/psysh 0.4.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.4.0, v0.4.1].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.7 requires psy/psysh 0.4.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.4.0, v0.4.1].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.8 requires psy/psysh 0.4.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.4.0, v0.4.1].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.9 requires psy/psysh 0.4.* -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.4.0, v0.4.1].
    - psy/psysh v0.3.1 requires nikic/php-parser ~1.0 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.1.0].
    - psy/psysh v0.3.2 requires nikic/php-parser ~1.0 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.1.0].
    - psy/psysh v0.3.3 requires nikic/php-parser ~1.0 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.1.0].
    - psy/psysh v0.3.4 requires nikic/php-parser ~1.0 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.1.0].
    - psy/psysh v0.3.5 requires nikic/php-parser ~1.0 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.1.0].
    - psy/psysh v0.4.0 requires nikic/php-parser ~1.0 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.1.0].
    - psy/psysh v0.4.1 requires nikic/php-parser ~1.0 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.1.0].
    - nikic/php-parser v1.1.0 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.0.2 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.0.1 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.0.0 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - psy/psysh v0.3.0 requires jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter dev-master -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.0.12, v5.0.13, v5.0.14, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I have a fresh global & local install of Composer on OSX 10.10. They both output the same error, and install fails.

I also tried git cloning laravel and then running `composer install` but I get the same errors.

Comment: Try `composer clear-cache` first? Or try `composer create-project laravel/laravel` (without the `--prefer-dist`)

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I cleared the cache, and ran your command but same errors. I'm really confused why this is happening. Can this be related to composer misconfiguration or something?

Comment: I tried myself create new L5 project and everything works fine for me. Try pulling different package if that works or its issue only with L5 installation.

Comment: @Kyslik on what operating system did you try? :)

Comment: Same as you :) 10.10.2, frankly I don't remember how I installed composer but I can  give you whatever info I can get if you need. Just ask here. I just checked I didn't install composer via homebrew but there is a Formula for it. The best shot is that I installed it using tutorial from their site (getcomposer.org).

Comment: @Kyslik Thank for your feedback. :) I don't understand what's going wrong on my side running composer... I gotta keep looking for a solution. This is a mystery for me

Comment: You know what, I see you use PHPStorm, go and create "new project" (blank), set up your composer.phar in PHPStorm preferences and then use "Composer->add dependency". To get where is composer installed use $ which composer. What does `composer -V` output?

Comment: @Kyslik Ok, The problem was that the 'tokenizer' extension was not activated in the php environment. Fantastic! Thanks :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Psy/psysh" needs "nikic/php-parser" and this one needs "ext-tokenizer".
Add/enable "ext-tonkenizer" extension from PHP and everything will work.

Comment: I've added a PR to Github to update the docs to show this requirement: https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/1240

Answer (score 1):

Install `ext-tonkenizer` steps:

```
cd /var/package/php-7.0.12/ext/tokenizer

/usr/local/php7/bin/phpize

./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php7/bin/php-config

make

make install

/usr/local/php7/bin/php -m | grep tokenizer
```

**tokenizer**